# knex.js - Table is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data

Tags: mysql, knex.js

I'm trying to run this code with mariaDB :

```
    let subq = knex()
               .select('id')
               .from('notifications')
               .where('user_id', 1)
               .orderBy('id', 'DESC')
               .offset(5)
               .limit(1)

return knex()
       .from('notifications')
       .where('id', '<=', subq)
       .where('user_id', 1)                       
       .del()
```

AND I get this error :

> Table is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a
>   separate source for data

I searched about it, and it seems that by using alias for inner statements
this issue can be solved, but I can't find a proper way to do that in Knex.js.

Comment: You can't both select and delete a table. First you should select the records'll removed to array ids. Then you delete them with query `.whereIn('id', removedIds)`

Comment: with postgresql that query did seem to work just fine... maybe mysql doesn't allow to do that.